# NodeJS, ExpressJS: How to let CSS/JS requests go through

Tags: node.js, express, get, request

I have a Node/Express application that needs to serve pages to users by their username.
For example, a GET like www.domain.com/username is handled by a:

```
app.get('/:username', function (req, res) {
var user = req.param('username');
...
});
```

The problem is there are local CSS/JS pages and these requests are not going through because they are going through the ('/:username') route.

This is my first time at a web application, so please educate me on what is the general way of handling this scenario? Should I make exceptions to requests with .css/.js extensions?

Thank you

Comment: Third argument to route handler (which is just a middleware) is next middleware in chain. Call it if yours `req.param.username` isn't really a username. Or rearrange app middlewares, so one that serves static goes 1st.

Comment: Thank you almigranto! I put a app.use("/", express.static(__dirname)) before going to route module and it works fine.

Comment: Note, putting the static middlware before your routes like that will be slower because it will have to check every request to see it it matches your static files. Generally it would be better to put all of your JS/CSS in a subdirectory and only mount the static middleware there.

Comment: Thank you loganfsmyth. I didn't think about that.